# Starting video after movement detection with Arduino and Python

Tags: python, sensors, arduino-uno

So i am trying to do a project for college, basically i have a room where a video is playing and have to make a program which detects when someone walks into a room and switches the video with a new one.

My idea, which i have started working on, was to use and Arduino board, with a PIR sensor and making a phyton program which starts the first video when the program is started, interrupts the video to start the new one when the PIR sensor detects someone walking in and sends the signal, then it keeps the video going until the end and when it ends it starts the first video back again, all this until the user presses a key to close the program.
But i have uncontered some problems:

1. i have been using FirmataExpress in Arduino and Pymata4 to try to send the signal from arduino to phyton, but i just can't get the right value in phyton;

2)The only idea that gets to my head it's to use pyautogui to open the video but it gets ugly because i cant't make a clean transition between the first and the second video without all the passages that python emulates to open the video, basically is just a manual video opening but made faster and it just doens't feel good.

So i would be very grateful if someone could bring some ideas o redirect me to some libraries that could be usefull to make the project work.
Thank you.

Comment: There's not enough information here.  Are you running Python ON the Arduino, or is it attached to another computer?  How are you signalling between them, exactly?  What are you using to display the video?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.